# validate all packages to be correct

Tags: debian, dpkg, checksum, hashsum

I have two machines. One of which started to act strange lately (aptitude segfaulting, apt requiring a library named lkbm.qo.6). As the broken machine is not vital to me, I don't want to squash and reinstall it from scratch, but to investigate the problem however long it takes.

So, I have second machine thats acting fine so I would like to scan all installed packages on the broken machine and have the libs hash checked against the good ones.

Of course I can write a script for that, but I wanted to be sure that nobody else has solved that already.

The point is that I don't trust the broken machine. While it being intruded by an outsider is unlikely in this situation I would love to have a solution that would work even then.

(I'd love to add a `validation` tag, but could not find one.)

Comment: Have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9463/what-is-the-apt-equivalent-to-rpm-v-verify-installed-packages

Comment: @goldilocks but `debsums` itself may be somehow compromised on the misbehaving machine.

Comment: @JosephR. but it's easy to check `debsums` offline (on a known-to-be-good machine)

Comment: @umläute Interesting. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @umläute would you care to add the approach to use `debsums` offline as an answer? Sounds like exactly what I want to do.

Comment: ah well, probably it is **not** easy. sorry for the noise and the false hopes

Answer (score 1):

If you want, for example, check md5sum for all file in /bin, you can:

- mount you /bin dir from broken machine into the good machine and then run a check with executables on the good machine.

Example:

```
for i in `ls /mounted/bin` 
        do
        md5sum /bin/$i >> broken.txt
        done

for i in `ls /bin` 
        do
        md5sum /bin/$i >> good.txt
        done

cmp broken.txt good.txt
```

But i'm not sure that this is what you are asking for....

Comment: Good approach. Unfortunately the two don't run the same system (debian squeeze vs. debian wheezy) So using my own md5sums won't work.

Comment: Could you create a virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, but I'd rather use md5sums from the package system.